# Android - Como desativar iluminação automática da câmera?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Gostaria de desabilitar a iluminação automática da câmera no Android. Quando utilizo a câmera por exemplo, se aproximo algo à lente enquanto filmo, ela deixa a filmagem mais clara.

Gostaria de saber se existe um método para desabilitar este recurso.

Estou trabalhando com `import ketai.camera.*;`